# Modulo of two large numbers stored as strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, biginteger

How to get modulo A%B where A and B are two very large numbers stored in a string variable in c++.
I know about(a^b)%1000000007
I know about(a%b) where a is large number.
But what if both a and b are very large

Comment: Proper algorithm for `a^b%c` works well on binary representation. So your problem is `large numbers stored in a string variable` since probably you are operating on decimal numbers. Internet is full of explanations how this algorithm works.

Answer (score 4):

Use a big number library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: can I use that for online contest in codechef or hackerrank?

Comment: "Since version 6, GMP is distributed under the dual licenses, GNU LGPL v3 and GNU GPL v2. These licenses make the library free to use, share, and improve, and allow you to pass on the result. The GNU licenses give freedoms, but also set firm restrictions on the use with non-free programs."

Comment: Download it, read the documentation, use it in your project and then, if you have questions, ask something specific here.

Comment: @manoj no you can't use GMP on sites like: `codechef` `hackerrank`. Since they are limited to standard library and this is the point that you are getting familiar with problems like `a^b/%c`. Ready solution would spoil the fun/point of the site.